# How to remove double quotes from data in OpenCSV library?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv, read.csv, supercsv

I am creating a CSV file with some sample data with using two CSV libraries - Super CSV and Open CSV and this is how they are storing data in CSV file and text file -
[image]

With Open CSV - there are some additional double quotes in the data and i want to remove them and make it behave as same as Super CSV.

When I am using `.withQuoteChar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)` it stores data like this -
[image]

How to handle this case and make Open CSV behave as same as Super CSV?

Comment: Do not use images for text here. CSV is text, same as code and logs. Share a minimum reproducible example.